# Android Open Accessory Protocol using javax.usb

Tags: android, usb

I'm working on getting any existing device communicating with Android devices. The device uses [javax.usb](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/jdoc/) (which is built on top of libusb) for usb communication and I am attempting to implement the [Android Open Accessory Protocol](http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/aoap/aoa.html) using it. The device currently recognizes the android device and registers the android device with my application. However when I try to:

> Attempt to Start in Accessory Mode - Send a 51 control request ("Get Protocol") to figure out if the device supports the Android accessory protocol.

I get a UsbStallException and my app dies. I know very little when it comes to usb from what I have been reading this should work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
byte req = (byte) (0x80 | 0x40);
UsbControlIrp irp = usbDev.createUsbControlIrp(req, (byte)51, (short)0, (short)0);
usbDev.syncSubmit(irp);
```

Any insights as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

PS: the device I'm running this on uses a 1.4 JVM so any solutions will be constrained by that